# How to preserve model values during postback?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model:

```
public class EmployeeDetails
{
    public int staffcode { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string designation { get; set; }
    public string department { get; set; }
}
```

On click of Search button, employee details are fetched from the database and model properties are initialized. These values are also shown on the View.

```
            dtEmpDetails = lib.RunSP("GetEmpDetails", lstEmpDetails);

            leaveBalanceViewModel.EmployeeDetail.staffcode = Convert.ToInt32(staffCode);
            leaveBalanceViewModel.EmployeeDetail.name = dtEmpDetails.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            leaveBalanceViewModel.EmployeeDetail.designation = dtEmpDetails.Rows[0][1].ToString();
```

There is another button Save. When I click Save, the Textbox values from the View get lost because again a Submit is happening.

How can I store the model property values and keep it available during postbacks?

** Edited **
View Code is as below:

```
<div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "AFLeaveBalance",FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <table style="border:none">
            <tr>
                <td style="border:none">Enter staff code</td>
                <td style="border:none">@Html.TextBox("staffcode", "", new { width = "100" })</td>
                <td style="border:none"><input type="submit" value="Get Details" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
      <br /><hr />  
     <table id="tblEmpDetails">
         <tr>
             <td style="background-color:#d2eef7; width:200px;text-align:left">Employee Name</td>
             <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmployeeDetail.name, new { @readonly = "ReadOnly", @class = "ReadOnly", style = "width:300px" })</td>
             @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EmployeeDetail.name)
         </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#d2eef7;width:200px;text-align:left">Designation</td>
             <td >
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmployeeDetail.designation, new { @readonly = "ReadOnly", @class = "ReadOnly", style="width:300px" })
             </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
             <td style="background-color:#d2eef7;width:200px;text-align:left">Directorate</td>
             <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmployeeDetail.directorate, new { @readonly = "ReadOnly", @class = "ReadOnly", style = "width:300px" })</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
        <br /><hr />

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "AFLeaveBalance", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table id="tblCurrentYear">
        <tr style="background-color:#d2eef7;color:Black;font-weight:200">
            <td colspan="4">
                @Html.Label("Year: " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString())
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color:#d2eef7;color:Black;">
            <td>Leave Type</td>
            <td>Leave Taken</td>
            <td>Leave Balance</td>
            <td>Leave Total</td>
        </tr>
        @*@for (int i = 0; i < Model.LeaveDetailsList.Count; i++)*@
        @*{*@
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LeaveDetailsList[0].LeaveType, new { @class = "ReadOnly", @readonly = "readonly", style = "width:80px; text-align:center" })</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LeaveDetailsList[0].LeaveTaken, new { width = "100" })</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LeaveDetailsList[0].LeaveBalance, new { width = "100" })</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LeaveDetailsList[0].LeaveTotal, new { width = "100" })</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LeaveDetailsList[1].LeaveType, new { @class = "ReadOnly", @readonly = "readonly", style = "width:80px; text-align:center" })</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LeaveDetailsList[1].LeaveTaken, new { width = "100" })</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LeaveDetailsList[1].LeaveBalance, new { width = "100" })</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LeaveDetailsList[1].LeaveTotal, new { width = "100" })</td>
        </tr>
        @*}*@
    </table>
    <br />
    <table style="border:none">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:600px;text-align:left;border:none">
                <input id="btnSave" type="submit" value="Save" style="width:100px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

}  
</div>
```

Comment: Have you generated any form controls (e.g. hidden inputs) for those properties?

Comment: If you don't generate form controls for values that you send to the view, then those values cant be posted back when you submit the form

Comment: Not getting. Do I need to keep any hidden field? If yes, how this field value can be accessed from the controller? Something like: @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.DateCreated)

Comment: I'm just taking a stab in the dark (you have not shown you view or the controller you are posting back to), but if your generate a control for `staffcode` in the view e.g. `Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EmployeeDetail.staffcode)`, then its value will be posted back and bound to your model. But if you don't shown the relevant parts of your code its impossible to be sure.

Comment: @StephenMuecke View code added

Comment: You are rendering controls for some of the properties of `EmployeeDetail` (`name`, `designation` and `directorate` - but not `staffcode` - and you have a second hidden input for `name` which will be ignored so its pointless) but they are not inside the `<form>` tags so they wont be posted back (also not sure why you have 2 forms in your view?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Do I only need a single Form even if there are two submit buttons? One Form has method Get and another has method Post.

Comment: In that case 2 forms are OK, although there are better ways or doing it. In any case, the main issue is that the controls for properties of `EmployeeDetail` are not inside a form, so their values are not posted bac to the controller.

Comment: The simplest way is to store all you need in session on the server and then to populate all you need from that session after submit.

Comment: @genichm Please post your answer as solution so that I can mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to store all you need in session on the server and then to populate all you need from that session after submit.

Comment: @RKh Yes, I did not encountered any problem with using Session variable in MVC 4/5 projects. Session[name] = ..... and then casting back (CastObject)Session[name], the only problem I can see in this solution is termination of the session due to timeout or application pool reset.